# vuejs slick is not working with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

vue-slick is working fine with static content. But when I am trying to loop through playlists of user.slick is not working.

html part:

```
<template>
    <slick ref="slickone" :options="slickOptions">
        <div v-for='playlist in user_playlists'>
            <a href="#">
                <img :src="playlist.image">
                <p>Playlist Name</p>
            </a>
        </div>


    </slick>
</template>
```

script part:

```
<script>
    import Slick from 'vue-slick';
    import './node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
    import './node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                user_playlists: [],
                slickOptions: {
                    infinite: true,
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    autoplaySpeed: 5e3,
                },
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getUserPlaylists() {
                this.$http.get('api/user_playlists/user-playlists')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.user_playlists = response.body.data;
                            this.$refs.slickone.reSlick();
                        });
            },
            updated() {
                this.reInit();
            },
            reInit() {
                this.$refs.slickone.reSlick();
            },
        },
        components: {
            'slick': Slick,
        },
        watch: {
            profileData() {
                this.getUserPlaylists();
            },
            user_playlists() {
                this.reInit();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have checked the documentation and used `this.$ref.slickone.reSlick()` but still it's not working.

Comment: `I am trying to loop through playlists of user.slick is not working.` where did you tried to loop through playlists ?

Comment: its inside the template.

Comment: When do you call `getUserPlaylists`? If you do not call it, then `user_playlists` is an empty array.

Comment: this is a child component of another component, on watch of profileData, it will be called. I forgot to add props: ['profileData'] in top.

Still its not working.

Comment: Might be an issue with not providing a unique key for the v-for elements https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key. But also "it's not working" could mean a lot of things. What exactly is not happening as expected?

Comment: @thanksd, thank you. The problem was of explicit key. add :key="playlist.id" and it works now.

Answer (score 14):

I have a similar problem, but I update the state only once. For me solution is:

```
    beforeUpdate() {
        if (this.$refs.slick) {
            this.$refs.slick.destroy();
        }
    },
    updated() {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            if (this.$refs.slick) {
                this.$refs.slick.create(this.slickOptions);
            }
        });
    },
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Can confirm the solution from Oleksii.B works perfectly

Comment: This solution + adding `:key` (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) worked for me.

Comment: The package should allow you to init slick where you want within the Vue life-cycle. Thanks this solution works.

Comment: Thank you, i started to waste some time on this and then found your answer. Now its working.

Comment: It worked for me (doing the destroy and the create inside a watcher), but I had multiple slideshows (of which I was showing one at a time depending on one prop), so I had to assign different refs and to do the same thing for every ref

Comment: this is the way

Answer (score 5):

You just have to wait data are loaded. You can use on the slick component :

```
user_playlists.length > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

simple solution is to use `v-if`

```
<slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions" v-if="user_playlists.length">
```

Comment: thanks, but after that it's not swiping. I'm using computed property for bind list of slides. If I made dynamically update the list it's corrupting. I mean solution is not simple as you mentioned.

Comment: @YasinYörük I don't understand what exact problem you are facing, my solution solves the problem when initially the pictures array is empty and it does not add the pictures, what the `v-if` does is that it renders the pictures only if there is a array that contains some content.

Comment: Actually yes you’re right. Let’s say, if array is empty at first state, it works. But array populate dynamically it corrupted.

Comment: @YasinYörük what do you mean by corrupted?

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry for my late reply. Ok let me explain it step by step. Let's imagine, we have an empty array list at the first state. v-if directive is perfectly working and slick carousel is not showing on the page. There is a button on the page that populating this empty array with item one by one. So every click push an item into array. After this action slick carousel is appear but not swiping. I mean I can't swiping between items in carousel. I think we need to re-render this component but I didn't find proper solution for my issue. So I decided to use another component.

Comment: @YasinYörük I am not sure this will work but just try `:key="yourArray.length"` on your slick, this may also have some side-effects.