# How to use vue-slick with v-for?

Tags: vue.js

So I am trying to make carousel with `vue-slick`. The problem is that when I am doing it like this:

```
<template>
    <slick ref="slick">
        <ul class="row no-padding" id="slick-carousel">
            <li class="col-4" v-for="data in responseData" :key="data.id">
                <project-tile :project="data"></project-tile>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </slick>
</template>

<script>
import Slick from 'vue-slick';
import { formBus } from './../../main.js';
import ProjectTile from './../projectTile/ProjectTile.vue';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            responseData: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        formBus.$on('fetchData', data => {
            this.responseData = data;
        })
    },
    components: {
        projectTile: ProjectTile,
        Slick
    }
}
</script>
```

it does not work. The problem occurs only when I am making my list with `v-for`.
Any solutions what should I do to properly use `vue-slick` ???

Comment: What problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: elements on the list are displayed but there is no `slick` funcionality

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49513790/10038915

Comment: @Jns it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wait data are loaded. You can use on the slick component :

```
responseData.length > 0
```